# Code Comparison : Which code is better to use in terms of efficiency?

Tags: c++, string, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

Which code is better to use : to initialize string ?

```
bool flag = /*function call...*/
string str = "abc";
if(flag)
  str = "bcd";
```

Or

```
string str;
if(flag)
  str = "bcd";
else
  str = "abc";
```

Or

```
string str("abc");
if(flag) 
  str = "bcd";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MarkusDeibel No, it would be closed as _lacking context_ there.

Comment: I suppose you want to benchmark this. I suspect the results will be different is you use strings of 40char instead of 3 char

Comment: `string str = flag ? "bcd" : "abc";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ way is to use initialization:

```
bool flag = foo();
string str { flag ? "bcd" : "abc" };
```

`flag` determines which string literal is used in the call to `std::string::string(const char*)`. But there's one call, one string object being constructed, and no assignment.

[edit] 
Flipped the string literals. In C++, both for the `if` construct and the `?:` construct, the "true" case comes first, and then "false" case last. But the question had them reversed, "abc" came first for the `flag==false` case.

Answer (score 10):

This is a micro optimization you should not be doing. A C++ program is **not** a description of assembly in human readable format. It's a a high level description of the behavior your program should have. The compiler's job is to emit assembly that exhibits the behavior we specified.

You didn't specify how you *use* the resultant string, but if I make a few a assumptions and turn your code into small functions...

```
#include <string>

std::string foo1(bool flag) {
    std::string str = "abc";
    if(flag)
        str = "bcd";
    return str;
}

std::string foo2(bool flag) {
    std::string  str;
    if(flag)
        str = "bcd";
    else
        str = "abc";
    return str;
}

std::string foo3(bool flag) {
    std::string str("abc");
    if(flag) 
        str = "bcd";
    return str;
}
```

.. Clang 8.0 will produce pretty much equivalent assembly for the three cases (and especially for `foo1` and `foo3`)<sup>1</sup>. You can see it on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/q0VEw4).

Which is no surprise, since the observable behavior your three snippets dictate is *the same*, and not affected by which snippet you chose. So don't dwell on micro optimizations. Dwell on describing optimal behavior on a greater scale.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - Well, there *is* a noticeable branch in `foo2`, but the code that will be executed at runtime is still always going to be one *potential* allocation and a copy of the string's contents. There may be *some* cost on branch misprediction here, but unless it's in a *really* tight loop, I wouldn't consider it worth considering. Moreover, the use of `std::string` in a such a loop may be deemed questionable itself.</sub>

Comment: Yet it's not *the same assembly* for case 2. If you look carefully, there are 2 calls to `string::replace` in case 2 (one for each branch). Also the performance effect will be different once the string exceeds the short-string-optimization buffer size.

Comment: @rustyx - I may have emphasized poorly. I did mean the "pretty much" to be more noticeable. I imagine the two branches are there because that's the amount of instructions that will need to be flushed on branch misprediction.

Comment: @rustyx - Considering only one branch will ever be executed, SOO or not, I don't think that branching warrants more that a footnote about efficiency, if at all.